# C++ 11 User Defined Literals with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, user-defined-literals

As far as I know UDL are included and supported in MVS 2013.

I have tried to do things such as:

```
    myclass operator"" _suffix();
    int     operator"" _suffix();
```

Both the above lines give errors at "" saying it expected an operator. My guess is that something is wrong with the project settings since the code should work and UDL is supported by MVS13.

What could be the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Nope, [not supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/02/c-11-14-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp.aspx) in VS2013, including the Nov CTP.

Comment: @Praetorian Therefore I have to install the Nov CTP right?

Comment: No, you need to let go of the belief that *some* available version of VS supports UDLs :-). Look at the link I posted, it shows, as stated in my comment, that the CTP doesn't support it either.

Comment: @Praetorian I just saw that table, then is there any update for VS13 to get the UDLs or do I have to use some other compiler that supports them ?

Comment: What part of the table or his previous two comments were unclear? This is not supported in Visual Studio. The end.

Answer (score 5):

User defined literals are not supported by MSVC 2013 or lower. They are however supported in MSVC "14" CTP and will be part of the eventual MCVC 2015 release.

Sources:
[C++11 Features in MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) and [VS 14 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx)